# Facebook API displaying full size image from a page post?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook API to pull posts into my website and currently I am not able to retrieve the full-sized image from a post, only thumbnails. For posts which are videos, I get a nice large image, but posts with images only display the thumbnail image.

Here is an example response:

```
[message] =&gt; She still likes to come home
                    [picture] =&gt; https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s480x480/1509768_949952475034523_5777855144535809574_n.jpg?oh=296a9975752be40f24a0e32d613328aa&amp;oe=54DCDB3A&amp;__gda__=1426487880_adf80b362906423f8952c92925766989
                    [link] =&gt; https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=949952475034523&amp;set=o.337363685362&amp;type=1
                    [icon] =&gt; https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif
                    [privacy] =&gt; stdClass Object
                        (
                            [value] =&gt; 
                        )

                    [type] =&gt; photo
                    [object_id] =&gt; 949952475034523
                    [application] =&gt; stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] =&gt; Facebook for iPhone
                            [namespace] =&gt; fbiphone
                            [id] =&gt; 6628568379
                        )

                    [created_time] =&gt; 2014-11-25T18:43:41+0000
                    [updated_time] =&gt; 2014-11-25T18:43:41+0000
```

Notice how the result in `[picture]` is a small image.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
function fetchUrl($url){

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

$feedData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

return $feedData;
}

$profile_id = "xxxxx";

//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

//Retrieve auth token
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}");

$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);
print_r($feedarray);
?>
```

Is there a different way to code this that will allow me to retrieve the full-sized image, or is there a way to restructure the URL that is returned to display the larger image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this old post; you must already have figured it out; still, the answer is for you to restructure your url in order to get the "attachment":

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?access_token={$authToken}&fields=attachments
```

You will get a "src" which will have a larger image.